# Webpack Build generation Issue, Module not found: Error: Can't resolve (Note: working in local pc)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have two imports

```
import OptionCard from '../OptionCard';
import RolesDropdown from '../RolesDropdown';
```

> First import is working fine in local system and aws server, but the second import has issue in aws server.

These imports are working fine in local system. when we try to do build in aws server, we are getting this error.

```
ERROR in ./public/js/react/Pack/Share/components/Forms/InviteByLinkForm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../RolesDropdown.js' in '/var/www/html/tigersheet/staging2/releases/release_1592082265023/public/js/react/Pack/Share/components/Forms'
 @ ./public/js/react/Pack/Share/components/Forms/InviteByLinkForm.js 13:20-50
 @ ./public/js/react/Pack/Share/components/Forms/Index.js
 @ ./public/js/react/Pack/Share/SharePopup.js
 @ ./webpack/js/app.js
```

> Node version 10

Comment: First thing to check, does the file exist with exactly that name (`RolesDropdown.js`)? The Linux filesystem used by your AWS server is probably case-sensitive whereas your local machine (if Mac or Windows) is probably not

Comment: Checked the server already, File is present. File name and the name in the import statement are exactly same.  Also first file has Capitals, which is working fine but the second one is not working

Comment: So in `./public/js/react/Pack/Share/components/`, there's both `OptionCard.js` and `RolesDropdown.js` files, spelled exactly like that (capital "R", capital "D")?

Comment: that's the issue, I didn't notice my file name was RolesDropDown.js. Thank you very much. can you write it as an answer, I'll mark that as answer